# Can IR balanced output from Engl ironball e606se plug directly to a monitor speaker

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, amplifiers, metal

I am buying a guitar amp and thinking about engl ironball e606se.

I have a limited space for my apartment, so I prefer a small speaker than 1x12 cab.

However, I don’t know that is it ok to use ir balanced output (xlr) and plug directly to a monitor speaker (for example, Yamaha HS7).

Comment: Yes, it _seems_ like XLR is a linear level output, which would be suitable to connect to a powered monitor like HS7. But manual doesn't say it explicitly, so the best is to ask the producer. Also, note the instruction to use power soak setting "speaker off" with IR post power amp setting.

Comment: So did you buy an engl ironball and pluged it into a monitor? If so, how is it? Is it works as you expect it to be? Or you regret you didnt get a solid amp like boss katana for example? I am now having the same conlict you had? Dont know if to buy engl ironball or to go for a solid amp or a kemper…

Answer (score 0):

This amp has speaker outs, so, yes, it can be plugged straight into a monitor speaker - a passive one. It should also be capable of connecting a powered monitor - via the XLR, but that will colour the sound somewhat. The speaker outs are jacks. But why ask us - why not ask the manufacturers and/or suppliers?

Comment: Guitar speakers are designed to color the sound, so plugging the amp directly to a monitor is not going to sound great. The XLR output has speaker emulation ("IR" stands for impulse response) so it should sound closer to guitar cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

The setup should work, because the XLR output has speaker emulation (the "IR" stands for impulse response, that is how the emulation is technically implemented).

However, this means that part of the signal chain is now emulated and the emulated cabinet and microphone combination will sound different than an actual guitar cabinet in the room. If the intention is to play at home at low volume and not care too much about having the real deal with tubes and guitar cabinet, a modeling amp might be a better option.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the last paragraph. Modellers emulate the microphone as well.

Comment: @user1079505 you're absolutely right about microphone modeling. But microphone next to the cabinet doesn't hear the same thing as a person in the room does. It's the sound and feel of actual guitar cabinet where modelers fail. But a cabinet restricted to bedroom volume isn't that great either.